# Xcode SwiftUI UITableView separator color form "section" text

Tags: xcode, forms, swiftui, sections, navigationview

Xcode 12 / Swift 5 / SwiftUI

How to remove the separator between each text label in a form that is inside a NavigationView?

I have this but I still have a separator between each Text, how to remove it?

```swift
struct ContentView: View {

    init() {
        UITableView.appearance().sectionHeaderHeight = .zero
        UITableView.appearance().backgroundColor = UIColor.white
        UITableView.appearance().separatorStyle = .none
    }

    var body: some View {

        NavigationView {

            Form {
                Section(){
                    Text("\(isbn ?? "")")
                    Text("\(foundBooks?.items.first?.volumeInfo.line1 ?? "")")
                    Text("\(foundBooks?.items.first?.volumeInfo.line2 ?? "")")
                    Text("\(foundBooks?.items.first?.volumeInfo.line3 ?? "")")
                    Text("\(foundBooks?.items.first?.volumeInfo.line4 ?? "")")
                    Text("\(foundBooks?.items.first?.volumeInfo.line5 ?? "")")
                    Text("\(foundBooks?.items.first?.volumeInfo.line6 ?? "")")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I though that inside `init` the line `UITableView.appearance().separatorStyle = .none` would do it, but it doesn't

what code and where to add to remove the separator between each `Text()...`

Answer (score 0):

Digging a bit I found this

```
Form {
                Section(){
                    Text("\(isbn ?? "")")........
                }.frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
                .listRowInsets(EdgeInsets())
                .background(Color.white)
            }
```